# I have a UIView inside of a UIScrollView. How do I reference the parent UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview, drawrect

I've finally figured out how to stick a UIView inside of a UIScrollView, but now I have the problem of not being able to call the UIScrollView (who is the parent of the UIView) from within my UIView.

I've tried something like:

`UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)self.superview;`

But that's not working. My thought process was that the superview would be the container for the current view (UIView), but that returned a UIView so I just casted it to a UIScrollView, which I turned out to not be the right guess.

Comment: How are you adding the view to the scroll view, in IB or in code?

Comment: in my AppDelegate, I have:
`- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
    // Override point for customization after app launch    
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}`

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. If you want people to help you, help them to do that by providing corresponding details. The question was how are you adding your view to that scrollView, not what arre you doing in applicationDidFinishLaunching or how are you attaching your first controller to the window...

Answer (score 3):

When you call

```
[someView addSubview:someOtherView];
```

`someView` is automatically set as superview of `someOtherView`. In your case, if this

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[self superview];
```

does not work (you probably have a typo in your question as the "=" is missing), then you have a problem setting things up (If that's the case, post your setup code).

Comment: the UIView is working properly (things are being drawn, touch is being responded to), so I feel as though it's probably set up correctly (I could be wrong).

But okay, at least I know that the call to the super isn't the problem.. probably has something to do with this:
`UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[self superview];
                CGPoint zoomPoint = [[slices_zoompoints objectAtIndex:index] CGPointValue];
                CGRect zoomedRect = [self zoomRectForScrollView:scrollView withScale:3 withCenter:zoomPoint];
                [scrollView zoomToRect:zoomedRect animated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the scrollView to the UIView, thorough IB or code.

**Through code you can add as**

[self.view addSubView:scView];

Before that you need to add all the fields, labels and TextFields to the ScrollView. and set tags to the fields for the reference.

**if u add textfield in scrollView ...**

[scView addSubView: TextFieldsName];